# Qt5: connectToHost() to receive broadcast udp datagram

Tags: networking, udp, qt5, broadcast

Can I use QAbstractSocket::connectToHost() to receive broadcast udp datagrams?

If I try the unmodified broadcastsender/receiver all works and netstat is:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
udp6       0      0 :::52337                :::*                                12185/./broadcastse 
udp6       0      0 :::45454                :::*                                12172/broadcastrece
```

I modified broadcastreceiver as follow:

```
//! [0]
    udpSocket = new QUdpSocket(this);
    udpSocket->bind(45454, QUdpSocket::ShareAddress);
    udpSocket->connectToHost(QHostAddress(QHostAddress::Any),0); // <- added line
//! [0]
```

Now it does not receive broadcast datagrams, but it receive correctly unicast datagrams.

the netstat command report is:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
udp6       0      0 ::1:45454               ::1:*                   ESTABLISHED 11488/broadcastrece
```

I wonder why it seems different local address, and where am I wrong.

best regards
Max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [official documentation of QUdpSocket](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qudpsocket.html#details) you will see the following paragraph which explains how to use QUdpSocket rather well:

> The most common way to use this class is to bind to an address and
>   port using `bind()`, then call `writeDatagram()` and `readDatagram()` /
>   `receiveDatagram()` to transfer data. If you want to use the standard
>   `QIODevice` functions `read()`, `readLine()`, `write()`, etc., you must first
>   connect the socket directly to a peer by calling `connectToHost()`.

So your call to `connectToHost()` is **not necessary**, you should instead just  bind and then listen on the signal [`readyRead()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#readyRead) and from the slot, use either `readDatagram()` to get the raw packet data or `receiveDatagram()` to get the pre-parsed data.

This might seem counter intuitive, but due to the nature of UDP protocol, there is no connection, and any node may send packets to any other node un-initiated, so once you `bind()` you can receive UDP packets from anyone.

The source address & port will in that case be part of the datagram itself. You can see this in the parameters to the `receiveDatagram()` function signature:

`qint64 QUdpSocket::readDatagram(char *data, qint64 maxSize, QHostAddress *address = Q_NULLPTR, quint16 *port = Q_NULLPTR)`

One note though, you might experience problems communicating over UDP because any translating gateways (NAT routers) will drop all packets since they are un-initiated. This is a common problem and unless you control the routers between the endpoints, will require some [clever tricks](https://github.com/shadeslayer/libnice) to get around.

Hope this was informative.